# Unable to start a Docker container through Remote Docker Java API

Tags: java, docker

I am a beginner to Docker technology and I have been attempting to build up a Java app which is capable of starting and stopping existing Docker containers.

For this purpose I had been using Java Docker API client - docker-java. 
https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java and I had been using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki test cases to observe how this API works as I have not been able to find any related tutorials.

Using the code, I have enabled the Java application to create a Docker container using the following code sample.

```
CreateContainerResponse container = client.createContainerCmd("chirangaalwis/docker-whale")
                .withCmd("/bin/sh -c '/usr/gam")
                .exec();
```

But I have been unsuccessful in starting up the container I created using the Java application and it throws out the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.dockerjava.api.InternalServerErrorException: Cannot start container 485386a92b34c5aaf53793207e5c6a8146295b23602c9d0adf86d64a1b27d031: write /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/485386a92b34c5aaf53793207e5c6a8146295b23602c9d0adf86d64a1b27d031/cpuset.cpus: invalid argument

    at com.github.dockerjava.core.util.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:334)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:28)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrDockerCmdExec.java:53)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:29)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:53)
    at lk.ac.iit.java_docker.DockerWithJavaClass.main(DockerWithJavaClass.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

This was the code sample I am using for the above purpose:

```
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.CreateContainerResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Container;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Info;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.SearchItem;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;
import com.kpelykh.docker.client.model.ContainerCreateResponse;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by chiranga on 7/29/15.
 */
public class DockerWithJavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DockerClient client = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("http://localhost:2375").build();

        System.out.println("This is my client " + client);
        System.out.println();

        Info info = client.infoCmd().exec();
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println();

        CreateContainerResponse container = client.createContainerCmd("chirangaalwis/docker-whale")
                .withCmd("/bin/sh -c '/usr/gam")
                .exec();

        client.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
    }
}
```

Based on the exception messsage, I changed the code such that the id is printed along with the full path given, which led to another new exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerException
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.util.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:334)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:28)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrDockerCmdExec.java:53)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:29)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:53)
    at lk.ac.iit.java_docker.DockerWithJavaClass.main(DockerWithJavaClass.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The following change was made to the code before I got the above new exception:

```
client.startContainerCmd("/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/" + container.getId() + "/cpuset.cpus").exec();
```

I am totally new to this technology and I would be grateful if someone could provide me with a well explained solution to this problem and if any better alternative(s) to achieve this task exist, please specify.

Comment: Just to let all the readers know, I found a better remote-API library which can be used to achieve the tasks I am trying to fulfill. The link to it is https://github.com/spotify/docker-client